# Inconsistent results with < and <= in C with max and min ints

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, clang

I'm writing some C code to look at the bit representations of integers. 
In the process I found code that returns different results based on optimization settings.  Am I just doing something wrong, or is this a compiler bug?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int test(int x, int n)
{
  int TMin_n = -(1 << (n-1));
  int TMax_n = (1 << (n-1)) - 1;
  return x >= TMin_n && x <= TMax_n;
}

int main(){

    int x = 0x80000000;
    int n = 0x20;
    if(test(x,n)){
        printf("passes\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("fails\n");
    }
}
```

If I compile it this way I get a passing result

```
$ gcc tester.c -o tester
$ ./tester
passes
```

If I compile it this way I get a failing result

```
$ gcc -O1 tester.c -o tester
$ ./tester
fails
```

The problem is that

```
x <= TMax_n
```

is evaluating as false in the optimized case only.

Here is my platform details:

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your platform apparently uses 32 bit `int` type. `0x20` is `32`, which means that `1 << (n-1)` inside your function attempts to shift `1` by `31` bit. The behavior is undefined, since this expression has signed type (`1` has type `int`) and value of 2<sup>31</sup> is not representable in it.

> **6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators**
>
> **4** The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. [...] If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

What you are observing is the consequences of that undefined behavior. There's nothing unusual in seeing its manifestations to depend on the compiler's optimization settings.

Comment: @djp3: C language does not have such thing as "just shift the bits". As you see above the `<<` operator is defined as multiplication by a power of 2. And if that multiplication overflows, the behavior is undefined. More precisely, if you want to "just shift the bits" make sure to use `unsigned` types as operands. With signed types once you start shifting out of (or into) the sign bit, things typically fall apart. Left shift is undefined, right shift is implementation-defined. On C++ side of things C++14 switched to  implementation-defined for this left shift. But C keeps it undefined for now.

Comment: @djp3: Note also that even if you compiled this as C++14 and ended up with the expected signed `0x80000000` after the shift, the subsequent unary `-` or binary `- 1` would still overflow things and trigger undefined behavior.